# Can ffmpeg pull images out of damaged AVI files?

Tags: ffmpeg

Can ffmpeg pull images out of damaged AVI files?

I found software before that was able to dig into any kind of file and pull out images but I can't find it when I search now. It was command line so I thought it might be ffmpeg. After experimenting with ffmpeg for a bit I'm 100% certain it was NOT ffmpeg, lol!

I have several damaged AVI files. One plays the first 20 min or so out of 40-50. The other 3 wont play at all. I've tried playing with a dozen different players. I've tried rebuilding with like a dozen different tools. No love with either. One tool was able to try to use the index from the file that does start to play, but then failed.

When I try to use the command:

```
ffmpeg ignore\_err -y -i xyz.avi image.%06d.png
```

But it still errors out...

```
[avi @ 000001f2bef5f7c0] Format avi detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[in#0 @ 000001f2bef4a7c0] Error opening input: Invalid data found when processing input
Error opening input file xyz.avi.
Error opening input files: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Are there any switches that will tell ffmpeg to plow ahead?

**Bonus points:** Does anyone know of a kind of image grabbing tool? GUI or CLI?

Comment: Re Bonus Points: One question per post please, and requests to recommend software are off topic on this site. Have you tried opening the file in VLC? In my experience it detects and offers to repair video files. It doesn't "pull images out of damaged AVI...", but it might be able to just rewrite file info to correct certain types of errors.